# Extracting information from a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, api

Programming noob here. 
Just wondering what the best way to extract specific bits of information from a string is with Ruby.

I have some xml from an api that looks like this:

```
<users>
  <user>
    <twitter_screen_name>Jason</twitter_screen_name>
    <kscore>81.78</kscore>
  </user>
</users>
```

I just want to get the username and kscore out.

Heres what I've got, just wondering if theres a more efficient way?

```
info = Array.new
username = info[3].split('>')
username = username[1].split('<')
username = username[0]

klout = info[4].split('>')
klout = klout[1].split('<')
klout = klout[0]
```

Thanks

Comment: Obligatory amusing "Don't parse XML yourself" link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an XML parser such as [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
doc      = Nokogiri::XML(your_xml_string)
username = doc.at('twitter_screen_name').content
klout    = doc.at('kscore').content.to_f
```

Trying to parse XML with regular expressions is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the Klout ruby wrapper, depending on what version you're using of Ruby.

This will work with < 1.8.6 : https://github.com/jasontorres/klout

This will work with >= 1.9.2 : https://github.com/mpautasso/klout  (fork from the prior)